# Bootstrapping the Granger Wald Test?

Tags: bootstrap, granger-causality, wald-test

I created full example code that conducts a Granger causality Wald test for the Chicken & Egg dataset:

```
library(lmtest)
library(aom)

#Load data
data(ChickEgg)
data = data.frame(ChickEgg)
data
# sample=54 data points, which is rather low.

# plot time series
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot.ts(data$chicken)
plot.ts(data$egg)

# For simplicity of the example, we don't check stationarity and assume stationarity I(0)
# Also, we assume the optimum lag length of the bivariate VAR to be 2

# Conduct Granger causality Wald test
VAR <- VAR(data,p=2)

# chicken ~ egg
wald.test(b=coef(VAR$varresult[[1]]), Sigma=vcov(VAR$varresult[[1]]), Terms=c(seq(2, by=2, length=2)))
# Could be rejected at 1%, p=0.00015

# egg ~ chicken
wald.test(b=coef(VAR$varresult[[2]]), Sigma=vcov(VAR$varresult[[2]]), Terms=c(seq(1, by=2, length=2)))
# Could not be rejected at 1%, p=0.41

# Results indicate that chicken Granger cause eggs.
```

This works.

Now comes the main question. As the sample size is rather small (n=54), I want to conduct a bootstrap test for the p-values.

I got following working for a simple regression:

```
library(boot)

# Test Original Regression
summary(lm(chicken~egg, data=data[1:53,]))$r.square

# function to obtain R-Squared from the data 
rsq <- function(formula, data, indices){
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample 
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
  return(summary(fit)$r.square)
}

# bootstrapping with 1000 replications 
results <- boot(data=data, statistic=rsq, R=1000, formula=chicken~egg)

# view results
results
plot(results)

# get 95% confidence interval 
boot.ci(results, type="bca")
```

Can anyone help me replacing it with the Wald test? And: How do I interpret the results?